# How do I get Outlook 2013 to open ".ost" file?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

Outlook will not start because it cannot open the `.ost` file. I have deleted the file and get the same answer the next time I start it up (with a new 0 byte `.ost`).

I deleted the original .ost file that wasn't opening and then Outlook recreated a new .ost file. I also get the same message when I open it in safe mode.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you tried starting Outlook in `Safe Mode`?  Have you tried starting it if you don't have a 0 byte .OST file?

Comment: where did you delete the OST from?

Comment: I deleted the original .ost file that wasn't opening and then Outlook recreated a new .ost file. I also get teh same message when I open it in safe mode.

Comment: What type of account are you on ? IMAP ? POP ? Exchange ? Gmail ?

Comment: Allen, please register your account here to keep your login. Then you can post comments on your question and their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

Control Panel -> Mail (Make sure the view is either large or small icons) -> Show Profiles.

From there, you can create an Outlook profile.

Make sure that, in the profile page, the new profile you created is selected as default an then Fire up Outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to delete your profile and start over. The .ost file will be recreated based on what is on teh Exchange server.

Comment: This sounds a bit risky; can you explain how this would help in more detail?

Comment: From Microsoft: Outlook Data Files (.ost) are used when you have an Exchange account and want to work offline or use or use the default Cached Exchange Mode. This type of data file is also used for accounts that you set up with the Outlook Connector for Outlook.com (formerly Hotmail). Outlook Data Files (.ost) are always copies of items that are saved on a mail server and don’t have to be backed up like Outlook Data Files (.pst).